# Why didn't Jango Fett kill Obi Wan and Anakin?

Tags: star-wars, attack-of-the-clones

In *Attack of the Clones*, Jango Fett kills Zam Wessel with a dart while Obi-Wan Kenobi holds her and Anakin Skywalker interrogates her. Why wouldn't Jango Fett kill Obi Wan and Anakin, too? Wouldn't this be the logical thing to do for a cold-blooded bounty hunter like Jango to end the inevitable further investigation?

Comment: Possibilities:  1.  Killing two Jedi would make it a much bigger deal than killing a failed assassin,  2.  Killing Jedi isn't very easy.  Jango learned that the hard way when Mace Windu lopped off his head.

Comment: The real question is why he used a hired assassin in the first place, instead of someone who's best plan didn't involve sneaking bugs in through a window.

Comment: @CallumBradbury What if the plan was for the Jedi to discover Kamino and receive their made-to-order army? Zem would be bait, and Jango will very uncharacteristically kill her with a weapon whose origins can be used to track him down.

Comment: @thegreatjedi that would make a good answer.

Comment: Jedi can deflect blaster bolts. Why would Jango assume he would be able to kill them, especially after they were aware of the danger?

Comment: Another question then is why didn't they sense the dart that killed Zem?

Comment: Is it even possible to poison Jedi? Could they use the Force to combat it? I bet they never get sick either.

Comment: @WadCheber I'm torn as to whether or not it's possible to learn anything when your head is removed...

Comment: @user11521, I remember Boba Fett saying that a decapitated head still could think for a bit (forgot how long). Albeit, it’s the the legacy of the force legends series.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It can actually be seen as part of the whole plot to destroy the Republic. If Jango had killed Obi-Wan Kenobi, then Obi-Wan would never have found Kamino and the clones, which was a trigger point for introducing them into the war and the ultimate instigation of Order 66.

Therefore the plan to destroy the Jedi and Republic from within would have failed/never come into action.

Comment: I think the strongly implied assertion that Obi finding the clones was the lynchpin of destroying the republic, without which the whole plan would have failed, might need a bit of substantiation. Or in other words, [I think you should be more explicit here in step two.](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Mfdic.jpg)

Comment: There does not seem to be any proof to this, but it is the only reasonable answer imo. Palpatine needs the Jedi to discover the clone AND droid armies or the war can't begin. This is achieved through Jango, who led them to both. As one of the galaxy's best bounty hunters, why would he use a Kaminoan saberdart unless he wishes to be found?

Comment: I think I heard about that in one of the CW episodes, but I can't remember which one.

Comment: @thegreatjedi: and another interesting point is that he was hanging out with the separatists *and* whoever ordered the clone army created to fight against the not yet existing separatists. There were not much people having that much insight of the plot. So why should he try to kill Padmé Amidala if not to push things forward. If we believe, he was just hired by the separatists to do that, why did he return to Kamino, just to return to the separatist’s base (leading Obi Wan to them) then, when his ordinary job wasn’t done…

Comment: @Holger You may not know, but Count Dooku aka Darth Tyranus is in charge of the clone army project on Kamino. Sifo Dyas is an excuse he ordered them to use on Obi Wan. The Kaminoans know who the Sith are and what they are planning to do with the inhibitor chip. So, very likely, Jango Fett is in on it too. Like I said, there's no explicit proof to support this answer, but the implicit evidence is all there. It's the whole reason Ep II exists (except for the romance part)

Comment: @thegreatjedi: that’s exactly what I wanted to say. Even if there is no proof, the actions of Jango Fett would make little sense otherwise.

Comment: @thegreatjedi Note that Obi-wan wouldn't be able to trace the dart if he didn't happen to have a friend who's an expert on exotic weapons. The same with finding Kamino itself - it seems that many of the other Jedi would just give up when the computer says "Nope, not there." Of course, Xanatoing Obi-wan and Anakin (two very stubborn and not exactly traditional Jedi) to be in the position to investigate this was likely part of Sidiuses plan as well :)

Comment: @Luaan: let’s see it the other way round: since everything was planned to evolve that way, Darth Sidious must have had a plan, how to eventually reveal the existence of the army “for the republic” to the senate. Letting two Jedi doing investigations discover it, is a very plausible way. If they don’t find out that this is a weapon from Kamino themselves, some other lucky coincidence will happen…

Comment: @thegreatjedi:  Actually, Sifo Dyas did order the clone army, but the bad guys found out soon after and killed him before he told anyone about it.  He had had a prescient vision that the army would be needed, but the rest of Jedi Council wouldn't go for it, so he acted on his own.  Otherwise the Jedi would have reacted to the discovery a little more strongly than, "Well, that was lucky!  Too bad about all the death and destruction, though."

Comment: Jango probably didn't know if he could both kill the jedi and escape in time.  They might have blocked it.

Comment: At least in the movies, they never say how Palpatine got hands on the Clone army officially, or how their existence was justified.

Answer (score 66):

There is, to my recollection, no canon answer as to why Jango did not kill Obi-Wan and Anakin (i.e. there is no material where Jango explicitly says why), but given the circumstances, a few assumptions can be made.

#### 1. He wasn't paid to.

Jango Fett was hired to kill Padmé Amidala, not the two Jedi. When his subcontractor (Zam Wessell) failed to do the deed, he decided to kill her to remove all traces leading back to him. That was simply cleanup, not business.

#### 2. Inconvenient

Killing two (or one for that matter) Jedi would likely result in a, so to speak, crusade for his capture. The Jedi would likely go out in force to find the culprit. It's hard to do business when a legion of space wizards are gunning for you.

Comment: Number 2 is often portrayed in police/military type shows, when "one of our boys" is killed they open a huge manhunt. I've always wondered if the jedi would do the same, as vengeance is not their way. It would pose a pretty harsh dilemma: Protect the jedi order at the risk of losing a few jedi to the dark side, a hard decision to make....

Comment: “…to remove all traces leading back to him” …using a weapon that allowed tracing back to him.

Comment: Regarding #1: as a contractor never do more than what you are hired to do without being paid. No matter if you are a construction worker, a programmer or a political landscaper (with a blaster): never do more than what you are paid for. Doing so anyway makes you a schmuck.

Comment: @Holger in all fairness, the dart didn't show up in the Jedi archives at all, it was an extreme coincidence that Obi-wan knew Dexter, who was one of the very few people able to trace its origin.

Comment: @Matt Taylor: it’s actually the opposite. If you don’t want to be traced, you’ll use a weapon so common that it could origin from everywhere, not a weapon so unique that if somebody recognizes it, there is no doubt about its origin. From Jango’s point of view, the Jedi database is irrelevant (it’s not even clear whether he knows what is in it or not), but only the fact that there *are* people knowing it.

Comment: @Kevin likely they would have simply sent off one or two jedi to investigate, who would likely be able to figure out what had happened.  Maybe not a manhunt, but it would be inevitable if Jango had to keep killing Jedi to keep them off his trail.

Comment: I always thought he had a plan to kill Zem with this dart even if she succeded in the mission. Killing Amidala would attract Jedi attention and please Trade Federation - a perfect bait. Jango did plan on being traced, may be not so fast. I also wonder how many Caminoans did know they where building a Troyan horse and if Order 66 was worded "Attack all Jedi" or "Attack all space wizards" or "Attack your direct superior". The latter could have passed as  part of normal training.

Comment: @Barafu Yeah, that may have been a part of the plan as well, we cant know for sure. And regarding the Order 66 phrasing, I believe I've seen a list of all Contingency Orders provided by the Supreme Chancellor to the Clone Army, where 66 is specified something along the lines of "In the event of jedi Officers acting against the Republic and after having received orders verified as coming from the Supreme Chancellor clones will remove these officers by lethal force." Granted, this comes from Legends material written by Karen Traviss, so take with a pinch of salt.

Answer (score 21):

As far as I know there isn't anything in canon which explains this, but one possibility nobody's mentioned yet is that Jango could only fire one shot before alerting the Jedi to his presence. After the first shot he lost the element of surprise. If he had used that first shot to kill Obi-Wan or Anakin instead of Zam, the remaining Jedi would likely have succeeded in interrogating her and learning Jango's identity. By silencing Zam instead, he succeeded in keeping his identity a secret, for the moment at least.

As for why he didn't try to kill Obi-Wan and Anakin in addition to Zam, without concern for the element of surprise, that's because he had no reason to think he could take on two Jedi and win. You'll note that later in the film even when faced with Obi-Wan, a single Jedi, on Kamino he tries to run rather than fight.

Comment: This seems more logical than other answers to me.

Answer (score 2):

This was addressed by Pablo Hidalgo in [Star Wars Insider #62](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Insider_62).

> **Q. Why didn’t Jango just kill Obi-Wan and Anakin when he had the chance, rather than kill Zam?**
>
> **PH:** Jango didn’t get to be the best in the bounty-hunting business by being rash. His payment for the Senatorial hit covered sub-contracting out to Zam, not eliminating two Jedi. It also didn't cover the risks involved in tangling with two Jedi if it wasn't absolutely necessary. Since he was the one who hired Zam, and she failed, it
> was his responsibility to clear up that mess.

Answer (score -1):

One Problem that was not mentioned so far is also that the dart itself was especially prepared by the Kaminosians....to kill Zam. It was specially crafted just for her.

So the dart wouldn't work for a Jedi. And if he had tried to blast the Jedi.....they have a very good reputation to not be very suspencible for surprise attacks (except if they trust someone or the plot aehem...the force calls for it).

Thus not only would killing a Jedi be a kill he wouldn't be paid for and get hunted for by Jedi out of all things.....it wasn't an assured kill like Zams. And killing Zam would also eliminate all needs to kill the Jedi as there was nothing pointing towards him (and Zams death was already planed anyway as the dart was prepared way ahead of time already).

Comment: Can you provide any evidence to back this up?

Comment: @Valorum it was mentioned directly in the film that the dart was crafted to work on her dna and that alone if you mean that. It was during the scene where obi wan sees her dying and investigates the dart proper

Comment: Where in the film is this mentioned? It's certainly said that it's toxic, but nothing about it being keyed to her DNA